# JScrollPane show only vertical bar and three dot for horizontal

Tags: java, swing

I want to add only vertical scrollbar for my panel. I can do it succesfully but in horizontal view there is no dots appearing for long texts. I want to see both vertical scrollbar and three dot for long texts that doesn't fit the screen. How can I do it? By the way If I add my panel directly to the frame dots appearing.

with scrollpane

[image]

when adding panel directly to the frame

[image]

```
public class ScrollPaneDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            panel.add(createLabel());
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        scrollPane
                .setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static JLabel createLabel() {
        return new JLabel(
                "Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text");
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem occurs because the layout manager has decided, for what ever reason, this the maximum amount of space available to display the panel, you might consider trying different layout managers

Comment: Also, .setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER); can't be helping

Comment: And which layout can give me the view whitch include vertical scrolbar and dots after texts.

Comment: Oddly enough, when I test this on my Mac I don't get any issues.  You could try using a `GridBagLayout`

Comment: The has to do with the `JViewPort`. The 3 dots appear because the *text does not fit in the panel*. When you use a scroll pane, the text does fit in the panel so there are no 3 dots, but the *panel does not fit in the view port*, and you can scroll to see the rest of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is surely a bad idea, but if that's what you want then here it is. Modify your panel to override its `getPreferredSize` to be its default height, but its parent's width:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

        int h = super.getPreferredSize().height;
        int w = getParent().getSize().width;
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }
};
```

The parent class is the `JViewport` which is the "window through which you look" at the component in the scroll pane.

Now the line

```
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

does nothing because it is guaranteed that the width of the panel is the width of the viewport, which means you have nowhere to scroll to and by default the scrollbar won't appear. The only way to see the remaining text is to resize the scroll pane through resizing of the frame.

I won't be surprised if anything breaks with this.

Comment: Thanks. Actually i changed my mind and did it with html. Even so your code works perfect.